# How to extract Values with M query / Excel

Tags: excel-formula, powerquery

I have this data in excel :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4YF3.png)

A        | B      |
NCR
10 - 15
17 - 20

I want a result like this

A            | B
NCR            10 - 15
NCR            17 - 20

I want a result like this

A            | B
NCR            10 - 15
NCR            17 - 20

this is the result that i want to have excel formula or mquery will do

Comment: You need to provide a before and after view, and sample data

Answer (score 0):

Im going to wild guess here...

In powerquery, right click the first column ... unpivot other columns